# "colour = ..level.." in "geom_contour" (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour

What does it mean double points in this syntax?

```
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(eruptions, waiting)) +
geom_contour(aes(z = density, colour = ..level..))
```

Comment: See "Computed variables" section of `?geom_contour`. The dot-dot syntax in `..level..` specifies a computed variable `level`.

Comment: More recently, ggplot2 has introduced `after_stat()` as replacement for the dot-dot syntax.   Any layer that has a non-identity stat-component has computed variables that you can access in this way.